# Обработка массива в C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, c++

```
int a,b,c,d,i,f,n,j;
int* Mas1 = new int[n];
a = Memo1->Lines->Count;
n=0;
b=a-1;
for (i=0;i<=b;i++)
{
    Mas1[n]=StrToInt(Memo1->Lines->Strings[i]);
    n=n+1;
}
Edit2->Text=Mas1[1];
delete (Mas1);
```

Данный код выполняется посредством нажатия на кнопку, однако, когда нажимаю на кнопку дважды, выскакивает ошибка, срабатывает только один раз в общем. Ошибка:

> "Invalid Pointer Operation"

А выпадает из-за этой строчки

```
 Edit2->Text=Mas1[1];
```

Почему не пойму. Что такого, что дважды записывается?

Comment: А чему равно n во второй строке? Нулю? Тогда нормально, Mas[1] не существует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка 2:

```
int* Mas1 = new int[n]; //n - не определено.
```

В последней строке:

```
delete (Mas1); //память освобождена неверно.
```

Следует так:

```
delete [] Mas1;
```

n, b - лишние переменные.

```
int a = Memo1->Lines->Count; 
int* Mas1 = new int[a]; 
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
  Mas1[i]=StrToInt(Memo1->Lines->Strings[i]); 
Edit2->Text=Mas1[1]; 
delete [] Mas1;
```

Comment: Немного не понимаю я ведь в массив закинул данные из Мемо. И если так то как лучше переделать?

Comment: Понял вас спасибо.